# How do I break an object away from linked data and edit keyframes?

Tags: animation, keyframes

I have a bunch of objects with linked animation data to a certain object. Now, I want to edit specific objects that I have linked animation data on. The problem is, I want to put some randomness in the different objects but when I go to edit the keyframes on one of the objects, because they're all linked together, I edit all of the objects. **Is there a way in which I can edit the keyframes on a specific object without editing all of the linked objects (without unlinking the objects)?**

Comment: In the Dope Sheet editor, if you switch it to Action Editor, you can click on the Create New Action button on the right of the current action name (double sheet icon), is it not what you want?

Comment: Or you can use NLA editor to freeze this action and add another action above and do some specific changes